# fill the gap between a simple GWT app to ROO (or backwards)

Tags: spring, gwt, jpa, spring-roo

I'm trying my best to use ROO, the problem is all I worked before was normal GWT apps created with eclipse and gwt designer. Also, I do know how Spring and JPA work, how DAOs are simplified with the use of aspects, and how to data is obtained from the DB.

When things go crazy is when I try the gwt setup feature... it implements one or 2 patterns and all I can say after is "where I place my .java from  my .client package now?" feels like a maze with the mouse trying to get the cheese from the DB

So, how do I work with these patterns now? or, is it possible to drop roo at a point where I could just use the Entities and keeping it like a normal GWT app with client/server packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GWT plugin for Roo was developed by google employees, that's why the generated application uses the best practices recommended by google. If you want to learn more about the generated application and how to customize it I recommend http://gwtsts.blogspot.com/ .
You can also ignore Roo and build your own GWT application. You can also remove Roo easilly (see this refcard http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/spring-roo-open-source-rapid)

Comment: ok, those 2 are very nice links, and as stated on the intro of the first one theres 4 things I gotta learn before this, thx

Answer (score 2):

Roo does not lock you in to using it so you can drop it at any stage, e.g. there is nothing stopping you from just making your entities with Roo and then not running the "gwt setup" step and just doing that stuff yourself.

However, I would not recommend that. The amount of GWT boilerplate code that Roo does for you is very beneficial. Another important point is that the GWT pattern Roo uses is MVP (Model View Presenter) which is considered the "best practice" GWT pattern. The first time I used Roo for a GWT app I knew nothing about MVP and I actually used Roo along with the GWT docs to learn concepts like MVP and UIBinder and it has proved very beneficial.

So I would suggest that you read up on the general MVP concepts and see how Roo has used these in the project that it created for you. A good place to start is [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html).

If you have any more specific questions to ask around why Roo has done certain things during the GWT setup then feel free to ask me, I should be able to help you out since I have put together quite a complicated GWT - Roo app quite recently.

Comment: I agree that I shouldn't drop Roo and that MVP is good. All the tutorials I find are oriented to how to use Roo more than the GWT part of the problem though.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a HelloWorld of how to create something other than the scafoldingapp set by gwt setup?

Comment: what HelloWorld example are you looking for exactly? A GWT-MVP one? If so, have a look I posted in my answer, it has such an example.

Comment: ye, you are right, thx for pointing out, is soo much to learn... I really wanted to update our previous client-server architecture but I got deadlines to meet...